# Single file for showing toast, alert, loader in Angular 4 for latest

Tags: angular

I am trying to develop a design pattern in which I have written code for all kind of informative widgets like toast, alert, popup, loader etc.

So my question is in which category of angular directory structure it will reside and is it right to do this thing?

For example:

```
import {
    AlertController,
    Loading,
    LoadingController,
    ToastController
} from "ionic-angular";
import {
    Injectable
} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable() export class Dialog {
    loader: Loading;
    constructor(public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public toastCtrl: ToastController, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

    }

    showLoading() {
        this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: "Logging In..."
        });
        this.loader.present();
    }

    hideLoading() {
        this.loader.dismiss();
    }

    showToast(message) {
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
            message: message,
            duration: 3000
        });
        toast.present();
    }

    showPrompt() {

        let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Tenant URL',
            message: "Enter the name of instance. Do not enter complete URL, just enter the name of instance",
            inputs: [{
                name: 'url',
                placeholder: 'Tenant URL',
                value: localStorage.getItem('baseUrl')
            }, ],
            buttons: [{
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    handler: data => {
                        console.log('Cancel clicked');
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Save',
                    handler: data => {
                        localStorage.removeItem('baseUrl');
                        localStorage.setItem('baseUrl', data.url);
                        console.log('Saved clicked');
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        prompt.present();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am currently using this approach in my mobile app build with ionic, ionic call it provider and in angular its a service. moreover i am sending the message from the component, so if i want to show loading with logging in message i call

> `this.infoProvider.showLoading('logging in')`

i am doing it in a provider, and i import it wherever i have to use it.

in ionic the command is `ionic generate provider providerName` and it will be generated in `src/providers/providerName/providerNameProvider.ts`

in angular the command would be `ng generate service serviceName` and it will be created in `src/app/serviceName.service.ts` you can leave it there or you can create a folder called services under app it is up to you.

> is it right to do this thing?

i believe so yes, AFAIK this is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks George! Can you please share that is it a best practice to make it a provider. I mean it belongs to the service category. It'll help me to decide it's place in directory structure.

Comment: let me edit the answer since i use ionic, ionic uses providers but angular uses services, they are the same thing its just naming